# How many API calls can be made per hour to a non-bulk endpoint?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, governorlimits, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

Assume that there was a REST endpoint that worked with 1 record at a time, i.e. not bulkified. If we were to use the Apex scheduler to pull down the records into SFDC every hour, what would be the maximum number of records that could be brought in within the 1 hour window?

We could use batches or other interfaces too. Whatever that helped maximize the record count. We can assume 2 seconds for the response time of each callout.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Outbound call API limit, the only limit come into the picture is Apex Async Job Limit which is 250K daily or the number of user licenses in your org multiplied by 200, whichever is greater.

You can do max 100 callouts in 1 batch iteration or in 1 transaction, after that you have to commit and start a new transaction. Batch seems a good option here.

Make a scheduler batch, the batch has chunks and they run serially. But then you can have multiple scheduler that runs multiple batches.

Maximum number of batch Apex jobs queued or active concurrently is 5

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Comment: What about the possibility of scheduling or executing batches concurrently?

Comment: Updated answer.